# Is it required to request Siri authorization?

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, siri

Do we need to request Siri authorization in the code and add the Usage text in the plist file? I ask because I was verifying the Soup Chef Demo and it does not do it.

Thanks

Comment: if you want your app approved on the store I would advise you to follow Apple's advice.

Comment: Yes you need something for Privacy using the plist entry - 'Privacy - Siri Usage Description' - you can find this in your project under the "Info" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need something for Privacy using the plist entry - 'Privacy - Siri Usage Description' - you can find this in your project under the "Info" tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll add the property on the plist file.